# Enviar e-mail tomando datos de una Base de Datos?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hola amigos/a(s) tengo un problema solo con una linea de código que por mas que busque no encontré alguna solución.

Uso laravel: 5.6
Mysql-MariaDB

Tengo esto:

Y en la parte de `$message->$usuario->email` que es al usuario que se enviara el correo. Me sale este error adjuntado abajo del codigo

```
public function restoremail(Request $request)
    {

    $correo=DB::table('usuarios')
        ->where('email', '=', $request->get('email'))
        ->get();  
        if(count($correo) > 0)
        {

            $usuario=Usuarios::findOrFail($correo[0]->id_usu);
             $data = array(
    'contrasena'=>$usuario->contrasena,
);
            Mail::send('emails.restore', $data, function($message){
        $message->from('developer.sr@hellomexico.mx','Helle Mexico Team');
        $message->to($usuario->email)->subject('Mensaje de prueba helloteam');

    });
     return view('Home.principal');
        }
        else
        {
             return view('error');
        }
```

[image: error]

De que manera puedo hacer que el usuario ingrese su correo para que vea en su bandeja de entrada su contraseña, y re-calco solo es esa parte donde el sistema tiene que tomar el correo, gracias por su ayuda!.

Comment: aunque pudiera sonar trivial, cual usas mysql o mariadb? o los dos a la vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No importa mucho la base de datos, lo que pasa es que no puedes utilizar una variable que no este pasada al `callback`, el tercer parametro de `Mail::send()` es un `callback` y es donde le tienes que pasar el parámetro con un `use`,  en tu caso `$usuario`.

Con esa pequeña explicación tu función quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Mail::send('emails.restore', $data, function($message) use ($usuario){
    $message->from('developer.sr@hellomexico.mx','Helle Mexico Team');
    $message->to($usuario->email)->subject('Mensaje de prueba helloteam');

});
```

Comment: Muy cierto, probando al fin funciono, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Listo ya puse la respuesta como aceptada